# C# : How to copy protected worksheet for a new excel file?

Tags: c#, excel

Someone please tel me how to copy a worksheet from a protected excel file,and create a new excel file with similar extension and some name,and add some macro to it.

Please somebody help me on this.

thanks

Comment: Will you required to use with c# coding? why you chose c#?

Comment: Where is the C# or was that just a ploy to get an excel question answered on SO?

Comment: If you really are looking for a C# solution, you're going to have to at least demonstrate you've attempted something yourself. No one is going to write your project for you.

Answer (score 2):

Open both workbooks.

Go to the cell where you want the information to show up in and type the
= symbol. Then go to the other book/sheet where the information is in the
protected sheet and click in the proper cell. Hit the [Enter] key. Done